# Send big frames by bluetooth at once without taking too long between one byte and another

Tags: android, multithreading, bluetooth

I'm facing a problem when send data from my Android to firmware. I need to send almost 1024 bytes at once, but when the android bluetooth is sending all those datas, in the middle of frame I got some delays (like 60ms) between one byte and another and I really can't this happening. 
I do believe this might happen because as we are in a multithread environment, the OS needs to 'answer' other applications and taking time to attend other applications and go back to finish sending the bluetooth data.

Does anybody knows how work around this problem?

Ps.: The frame is breaking just sometimes, not each big frame.

[image: Example about what is happening]

Answer (score 0):

Possibly it is the work of `L2CAP` to do a `segmentation` of big packets to promise good communication [or no loss of data].

And the differing communication quality can be the reason why it occurs at random.